# could not connect to smtp host:smtp.gmail.com, port:465

Tags: java, android, email

could not connect to smtp host:smtp.gmail.com, port:465
i have searched a lot and changed the port many time but same error appear each time like port 567, 25 and so on but no use ... 
Thank you in advance
UserPage.java is

```
   package com.example.androidphp;

   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

   import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

   import android.annotation.TargetApi;

   import android.os.Build;

   import android.os.Bundle;

   import android.os.StrictMode;

   import android.util.Log;

   import android.view.MenuItem;

   import android.view.View;

   import android.widget.Button;

   import android.widget.TextView;


  public class UserPage extends ActionBarActivity {

  Button button;

  TextView txtvw;

  String text;

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")

  @Override

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.userpage);

    txtvw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

    button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    text = "";

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

             try {   

                 System.out.println("in try");

                   GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("sidzyum@gmail.com", "yum12345");

                     sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   

                         "This is Body",   

                            "sidzyum@gmail.com",   

                            "sadiaasgharnov@gmail.com");  

                         System.out.println("after mail send ");

                    } catch (Exception e) {   

               Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e); 

                   e.printStackTrace();

                }

        }

     });

   }


@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will

    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long

    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

 }
```

and GmailSender.java is

```
   package com.example.androidphp;

   import javax.activation.DataHandler;   

   import javax.activation.DataSource;   

   import javax.mail.Message;   

   import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   

   import javax.mail.Session;   

   import javax.mail.Transport;   

   import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   

   import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   

   import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   

   import java.io.IOException;   

   import java.io.InputStream;   

   import java.io.OutputStream;   

   import java.security.Security;   

   import java.util.Properties;   

  public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   

   private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   

   private String user;   

   private String password;   

   private Session session;   

   static {   

    Security.addProvider(new com.example.androidphp.JSSEProvider());   

 }  

public GmailSender(String user, String password) {   

    this.user = user;   

    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   

    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   

    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");   

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");   

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   

            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   

    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   

}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   

    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   

}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) 

throws Exception {   

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   

    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), 

    "text/plain"));   

    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   

    message.setSubject(subject);   

    message.setDataHandler(handler);   

    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   

    else  

        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   

    Transport.send(message);   

}   

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   

    private byte[] data;   

    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   

        super();   

        this.data = data;   

        this.type = type;   

    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   

        super();   

        this.data = data;   

    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   

        this.type = type;   

    }   

    public String getContentType() {   

        if (type == null)   

            return "application/octet-stream";   

        else  

            return type;   

    }   


    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   

    }   

    public String getName() {   

        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   

    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   

        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   

    }   

  }   

 }
```

and JSSEProvider is

```
  package com.example.androidphp;

 import java.security.Provider;


 import java.security.AccessController;

 public class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

     /**

     * 

     */

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public JSSEProvider() {

        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");

        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {

            public Void run() {

                put("SSLContext.TLS",

                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");

                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");

                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",

                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");

                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",

                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");

                return null;

            }

        });

     }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you telling it to use ssl?

Add this line:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
```

in your GmailSender constructor.

Answer (score 0):

keep the port no: as 465....
try changing the session value as

```
session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }
});
```

also change the security settings of less secure apps in your account by clicking the link below:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

Turn off antivirus or add an exception. Worked for me. And use application specific password if its gmail